# Get Parent's global variable value in Child-- jquery?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I am having Parent.aspx page where i have a button click(First Button).

On the click on button i get some fields which are as Global variables

And on right click of that fields which are in accordion i get a Popup which is User Control.

For this Popup(ChildOne.ascx) i have Auto Complete(ChildTwo.ascx) 
For these values to generate i need to send the result value of the First Button click.

Finally i want Child.ascx to access the Global Variable from Parent.aspx..,

I have tried Like this in my Child.ascx

```
 $('.element').parents('.pnlAccordion h3 VoyageMasterID')
```

But these is Not working, so is there any other way to get Parent element

Comment: If you're using ASPX your ID isn't the same server side as client side, try setting the ClientIDMode to "Predictable" and right click the element and click inspect element to get it's Client ID. In addition you need a # in front of IDs.

Comment: Here instead of ID iam using class names , class names of panel and div and the variable '.pnlAccordion h3 VoyageMasterID'

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.element').parents.find('.pnlAccordion h3 VoyageMasterID')
```

Comment: But is this the correct way to access Global Variable or a simply a Variable?? or do i need to include # before it??